# JObject.ToObject<T>() extension method transforms datetime values stored as strings

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net

When calling ToObject on JObject with a string property, transforms datetime value.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = JObject.Parse("{\"aprop\":\"2012-12-02T23:03:31Z\"}");

        var jobject = a.ToObject<A>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public string AProp { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is I get my value transformed despite it being a string. The ISO8601 specific characters got skipped:

[image]

I expect no tranformations to happen and want to be able to do date validation and culture-specific creation myself. I also tried the next code without success:

```
var jobject = a.ToObject<A>(new JsonSerializer
    {
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
    });
```

The *JObject.Parse* is introduced for example's sake. In my real task I have a Web.Api action on a controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(JObject[] requestData)
{  
    var jobject = a.ToObject<A>();
    return SomeCleverStaffResponse();
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you want is

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>("{\"aprop\":\"2012-12-02T23:03:31Z\"}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

as soon as you do `Parse` since "2012-12-02T23:03:31Z\" is a date the parser creates a Date Object everything after that will already have the object parsed so the `.ToObject` is useless as what you are doing is going from date to string and that's why you get the "12/...".

Answer (score 0):

Why do you *parse* it, when you don't want to have it parsed, at the first place? There's no reason for building a `JObject` instance. Just deserialize the string using the [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize__1.htm) method directly into an `A` instance. You can then leverage all Json.NET's attributes (among other means) to control deserialization as you want.

Comment: I parse it for example's sake, I get JObject as parameted in Web Api action. What I can't get my head around is why should I use Deserialize or DeserializeObject method and cannot tweak the .ToObject() method?

Comment: Why do you want to *tweak* something if there's a *straightforward* way? Maybe you are not telling the whole context.

Comment: I have not found a ***straightforward*** way to do it using .ToObject(), you may notice that the symbols specific to ISO8601 were skipped.

Comment: @Yurii what does your Web API method signature look like?