# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.ToObject() converting date in string format

Tags: c#, json, date, .net-core

I'm building a .net core library. The error is true for 1.1 as well as 2.0.

I have a `JObject` (I read a bunch of other answers where people tell the OP to just do `JsonConvert.Deserialize(obj)`, that's not an option, I need to have it).

That `JObject` has a date in a string, and I'm going to deserialize it to an object that also has it as a string, and I need to have it in the same format as it is provided.

One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554468/jobject-toobjectt-extension-method-transforms-datetime-values-stored-as-stri#21556411) I saw claims that as soon the object becomes a `JObject` the date is parsed to that format, but I found that that's not the case and `.ToObject()` is where this conversion is actually happening.

I searched a lot on here and found a couple of accepted solutions that do not work for me.

1. [Setting `DateParseHandling.None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549736/jobject-toobject-crashes-on-a-bad-date-conversions)
2. [Explicitly specifying the date format.(tried the other approach in this answer as well)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971228/force-jobject-to-serialzie-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

None of those worked.

Testing code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace JobjectDateTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"{""Data"": {""CreatedAt"":""2018-01-04T14:48:39.7472110Z""}}";
            var thing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(thing.Data.First); // "CreatedAt": "2018-01-04T14:48:39.747211Z"

            var jsonSer = new JsonSerializer { DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" };
            var innerThing = thing.Data.ToObject<InnerThing>(jsonSer);

            Console.WriteLine(innerThing.CreatedAt); // 01/04/2018 14:48:39
            Console.WriteLine(innerThing.CreatedAt == "2018-01-04T14:48:39.7472110Z"); // false

            jsonSer = new JsonSerializer { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None };
            innerThing = thing.Data.ToObject<InnerThing>(jsonSer);

            Console.WriteLine(innerThing.CreatedAt); // 01/04/2018 14:48:39
            Console.WriteLine(innerThing.CreatedAt == "2018-01-04T14:48:39.7472110Z"); // false
        }

        class Thing
        {
            public JObject Data { get; set; }
        }

        class InnerThing
        {
            public string CreatedAt { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to not use `innerThing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InnerThing>(thing.Data.ToString());`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've been experimenting when *serializing* the data, but the conversion is happening when you *deserialize* the JSON to start with. That's where you need to disable `DateParseHandling`. Here's the change you need:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None };
var thing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing>(json, settings);
```

New output:

```
"CreatedAt": "2018-01-04T14:48:39.7472110Z"
2018-01-04T14:48:39.7472110Z
True
2018-01-04T14:48:39.7472110Z
True
```

You can see the difference in the `JObject` this way:

```
var property = (JProperty) thing.Data.First;
var value = (JValue) property.Value;
Console.WriteLine(value.Type);
```

Before specifying the settings, this prints `Date`. With the settings preventing date parsing, this prints `String`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it with

`JToken rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myJsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None }) as JToken;`

As others wrote, once you have the `JObject` / `JToken` it is already too late for the `DateParseHandling`, and the `DateParseHandling` is not available for the `JToken.Parse()`.

```
JToken rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myJsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None }) as JToken;
if (rootObj.Children<JProperty>().Count() != 1) Console.WriteLine($"Error: json no or multiple root tokens");
JProperty rootProp = rootObj.Children<JProperty>().First(); // with the property you can access the name if needed
if (rootProp.Name.Equals("theTokenNameIAmLookingFor"))
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"found my token name: {rootProp.Name}");
      MyClass myObj = rootObj.ToObject<MyClass>();
   }
```